# Semantic grid system

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

We've started to use twitter's bootstrap, specifically just all the .less files.

One thing that's bothering me, is all the extra classes in my html, for instance.. I don't want my page to look like this:

```
<header class="row">
</head>
<section class="row">
</secton>
<footer class="row">
</footer>
```

So normally with less I could just fix this, by doing:

```
header {

  .row;

}
```

or

```
header {

  #gridSystem > .row;

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work..

What would be the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use the new version of Bootstrap 2 with new grid system:

```
header {
    #gridSystem > .generate(@gridColumns, @gridColumnWidth, @gridGutterWidth);
}
```

References:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/upgrading.html

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less

http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces

Comment: can you explain more on it? I'm not sure if I got it. Thanks